# Android 2.3.3 ListView with ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a ListView and  TextView. They are both in a `LinearLayout`. And this `LinearLayout` is inside the `ScrollView`. So it looks  like this:

```
Linearlayout
ScrollView
linearlayout
ListView
TextView
Linearlayout
ScrollView
linearlayout
```

But you can't scroll through it.
It just displays the `ListView`. And the `ListView` is cropped for some reason.

Is this normal? If not then how to solve this?

Comment: Please include your XML to clarify `Linearlayout ScrollView linearlayout ListView TextView Linearlayout ScrollView linearlayout`

Comment: why you use scroll view when you already have Listview...ListView always scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following xml code.If i am right you don't need Listview.you can do this with only text view. Here is code for Scrolling Listview.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>   
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this is a problem because list-view is already a scroll-view. Basically, when you encapsulate a scroll-view inside another scroll-view, android has no way to know which scroll-view the user wants to scroll. Generally, the bottom-most layer is scrolled. `iOS` still gets you through this problem in certain cases but android never does. You'll get weird scrolling characteristics. You can put a horizontal scroll-view inside a vertical one and that'll work fine. So I'd recommend changing your design in a way that you do not use the `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same problem.

Just change your `ScrollView` tag into `HorizontalScrollView` inside your **xml** and you're done.